# headers already sent (Magento1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I installed a module for Free shipping,

But as soon as installing module, when I try to update my cart on cart page, I got this error [image]

I am not able to trace the error as there is no bug in the module

The code of the module,  where the error above is pointing to is this,

Freeshipment.php

```
<?php
class Ameex_Freeship_Model_Carrier_Freeshipment extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
        protected $_code = 'ameex_freeship';    
        public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request) {
             if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
                return false;
            }
                $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
                    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
                    $groupid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
                    }else{
                    $groupid='0';
                    }
                $customergroupconfigdata=$this->getConfigData('customergroup');
                $grouparray=explode(',',$customergroupconfigdata);          
                    if (($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $this->getConfigData('ameex_free_shipping_subtotal') && in_array($groupid,$grouparray))
                ) { 
                   $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

                    $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
                    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

                    $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
                    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

                    $method->setPrice('0.00');
                    $method->setCost('0.00');   
                $result->append($method);           
                }       
        return $result;
        }
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array('ameex_freeship' => $this->getConfigData('name'));
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide code with in that or provide code you have tried

Comment: Now you can take a look

Comment: Can you add the actual error content instead of the screenshot?

Comment: As error was on LIVE site, we temporarily all modules. Thats why the screen shot is uploaded